# Generic parameter constraint on class crashes the compiler

Tags: swift, crash

This is a simplified form of some swift3 code:

```
class GenericListViewModel<CellViewModel> {
    let cells: [CellViewModel]

    required init(cells: [CellViewModel]) {
        self.cells = cells
    }
}

class ViewController<CellViewModel, ListViewModel: GenericListViewModel<CellViewModel>> {
    var viewModel: ListViewModel

    init(cellViewModels: [CellViewModel]) {
        viewModel = ListViewModel(cells: cellViewModels)
    }
}
```

The compiler crashes with the following error:

> 1. While emitting IR SIL function @_TFC4Xxxx14ViewControllercfT14cellViewModelsGSax__GS0_xq__ for 'init'
>      at /.../GenericStuff.swift:22:5

Am is missing something, or is this a Swift compiler bug?

**Edit**:

I reported this here https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3315 and it looks like it's fixed in current swift master branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pushing the system too hard with inheritance. Generics based on subclasses of other generics tends to break the compiler's brain, and is usually not really what you meant anyway. (That said: there is never an excuse for the compiler crashing, so you should absolutely open a [bugreport](http://bugs.swift.org).)

Do you really mean to subclass `GenericListViewModel` and then parameterize `ViewController` on that precise subclass? This seems very over-complicated and I'm not seeing how you would get any actual value out of it (since you can't rely on any additional methods added to your subclasses, and you already have dynamic dispatch). You're using both subclasses and generics to solve the same problem.

What you likely mean is that there's a `CellViewModel` and you want `GenericListViewModel<CellViewModel>` to wrap that, and aren't thinking about subclasses at all.

So, assuming you don't really mean to parameterize this specifically, let inheritance do its job. `ListViewModel` should be `typealias`, not a type parameter:

```
class ViewController<CellViewModel> {
    typealias ListViewModel = GenericListViewModel<CellViewModel>
    var viewModel: ListViewModel

    init(cellViewModels: [CellViewModel]) {
        viewModel = ListViewModel(cells: cellViewModels)
    }
}
```

Now it's fine. That said, do you really need the view model to be a reference type? View models often don't need identity themselves (unless you're observing them with KVO). They may wrap a reference type, but as an adapter, a value type is often fine. Assuming this is true for you, then this can and should be simplified to a struct:

```
struct GenericListViewModel<CellViewModel> {
    let cells: [CellViewModel]
}

class ViewController<CellViewModel> {
    typealias ListViewModel = GenericListViewModel<CellViewModel>
    var viewModel: ListViewModel

    init(cellViewModels: [CellViewModel]) {
        viewModel = ListViewModel(cells: cellViewModels)
    }
}
```

---

To your goals of "custom logic like filtering the model, or keeping some other state specific to each controller," I would be very careful of using subclasses for this. It sounds like you're tempted to mix too much functionality into a single type. First, think about how you'd call your code the way you're thinking about it. `ListViewModel` isn't constrained by the `init` call, so you can't use type-inference. You'll have to initialize it like:

```
let vc: ViewController<SomeCellModel, GenericListViewModelSubclass<SomeCellModel>> = ViewController(cells: cells)
```

That's pretty hideous and is fighting all the things Swift wants to help you with. Since you want to be able to pass in the ListViewModel type, let's just pass it in. This is what protocols are for, not classes.

```
protocol CellViewModelProviding {
    associatedtype CellViewModel
    var cells: [CellViewModel] { get }
}

class ViewController<ListViewModel: CellViewModelProviding> {
    var viewModel: ListViewModel

    init(listViewModel: ListViewModel) {
        viewModel = listViewModel
    }
}
```

Now we can create different providers.

```
// A more standard name for your GenericListViewModel
struct AnyListViewModel<CellViewModel>: CellViewModelProviding {
    let cells: [CellViewModel]
}

struct FilteredListViewModel<CellViewModel>: CellViewModelProviding {
    var cells: [CellViewModel] {
        return unfilteredCells.filter(predicate)
    }

    var unfilteredCells: [CellViewModel]
    var predicate: (CellViewModel) -> Bool
}
```

Now we can use it with:

```
let vc = ViewController(listViewModel: AnyListViewModel(cells: [1,2,3]))
let vc2 = ViewController(listViewModel: FilteredListViewModel(unfilteredCells: [1,2,3],
                                                              predicate: { $0 % 2 == 0 }))
```

So that's pretty nice, but we could do better. It's kind of annoying to have to wrap our cells up in an `AnyListViewModel` in the normal case. We could probably create a factory method to get around this, but yuck. The better answer is to make use of the power of `AnyListViewModel` to be a [type eraser](http://www.robnapier.net/erasure). This is going to get a little more advanced, so if you're happy with the above solution, you can stop, but let's walk through it because it's really powerful and flexible if you need it.

First, we convert `AnyListViewModel` into a full type eraser that can accept either another view list model, or just an array.

```
struct AnyListViewModel<CellViewModel>: CellViewModelProviding {
    private let _cells: () -> [CellViewModel]
    var cells: [CellViewModel] { return _cells() }

    init(cells: [CellViewModel]) {
        _cells = { cells }
    }

    init<ListViewModel: CellViewModelProviding>(_ listViewModel: ListViewModel)
        where ListViewModel.CellViewModel == CellViewModel {
            _cells = { listViewModel.cells }
    }
}
```

Now `ViewController` doesn't have to care what kind of `ListViewModel` is passed. It can turn anything into an `AnyListViewModel` and work with that.

```
class ViewController<CellViewModel> {
    var viewModel: AnyListViewModel<CellViewModel>

    init<ListViewModel: CellViewModelProviding>(listViewModel: ListViewModel)
        where ListViewModel.CellViewModel == CellViewModel {
            viewModel = AnyListViewModel(listViewModel)
    }

    init(cells: [CellViewModel]) {
        viewModel = AnyListViewModel(cells: cells)
    }
}
```

OK, that's cool, but it's not a huge improvement. Well, let's rebuild `FilteredListViewModel` and see what that gets us.

```
struct FilteredListViewModel<CellViewModel>: CellViewModelProviding {
    var cells: [CellViewModel] {
        return listViewModel.cells.filter(predicate)
    }

    private var listViewModel: AnyListViewModel<CellViewModel>
    var predicate: (CellViewModel) -> Bool

    // We can lift any other listViewModel
    init<ListViewModel: CellViewModelProviding>(filtering listViewModel: ListViewModel,
         withPredicate predicate: @escaping (CellViewModel) -> Bool)
        where ListViewModel.CellViewModel == CellViewModel {

            self.listViewModel = AnyListViewModel(listViewModel)
            self.predicate = predicate
    }

    // Or, just for convenience, we can handle the simple [cell] case
    init(filtering cells: [CellViewModel], withPredicate predicate: @escaping (CellViewModel) -> Bool) {
        self.init(filtering: AnyListViewModel(cells: cells), withPredicate: predicate)
    }
}
```

This is where things get powerful. We've said `FilteredListViewModel` can take some cells and filter them, sure. But it can also filter *any other view list model*.

```
let someList = AnyListViewModel(cells: [1,2,3])
let evenList = FilteredListViewModel(filtering: someList, withPredicate: { $0 % 2 == 0 })
```

So now you can chain things together. You could glue together filtering with sorting or something that modified the cells or whatever. You don't need one super-specialized subclass that does everything you need. You can click together simpler pieces to build complex solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Indeed, the `GenericListViewModel` can be used as it is in most controllers of my app. But there are places where the viewModel will have to handle some custom logic like filtering the model, or keeping some other state specific to each controller. So being able to subclass it would be really useful.